# Can people see who owns a branded channel?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

If I make a branded YouTube channel under my real one (which I am doing simply so my name isn't attached, and in actual fact would like the channel to be anonymous, so no-one knows who actually owns it), are people able to trace the channel back to my real one?

So for example, if I have my channel Finn Rayment, and then decide to make a branded one under Finn, known as Anonymous, would subscribers or rather anyone who sees Anonymous, be able to find who owns it other than simply telling ones voice or location on-video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there are no public ties between your personal and brand accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need to make a Google+ page for each YouTube account, so the account will be associated with that, at least. And there's a limit, I think it is 50 YouTube channels with one Google ID/email.